# Return count of Contacts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to return the count of all contacts in Microsoft Graph?

At the moment I am using the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts` endpoint to return a paginated list of contacts but I would like to know before I begin how long it's going to take to sort through them all.

Having a count return before-hand would be very useful here. I can't find this anywhere in the docs though.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the `$count` segment at the end should provide the collection count (if the service supports it). In this instance however, I see a value of -1 being returned upon `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/$count`.

Answer (score 0):

When I make this call via [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/Contacts/$count
```

I get the following result,

```
cache-control: private
client-request-id: 9ff7a409-b3d5-4123-b0ad-aeb267ca0ad1
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
request-id: 9ff7a409-b3d5-4123-b0ad-aeb267ca0ad1

4
```

So, it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 the current graph Api want you to request count as shown below

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/Contacts?$count=true
```

Which returns

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('7c5ad5-af40-41a4-88a3-a0a37971d16f')/contacts",
    "@odata.count": 0,
    "value": []
}
```